# Shiny app error: "Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Tags: r, shiny, operators

I am at my wits end trying to figure out why my shiny app isnt working. I am new to this and tried many things to get it working.

Oddly enough the app was working fine locally. I uploaded the app to shinyapps.io and got this error in the logs.
[error shown in shinyapps.io log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWc4z.png)

In the process of trying to solve the problem I updated the rsconnect package and now am receiving this same error when running the app locally.

it looks like this on the app
[error as shown on app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c20g.png)

the error in RStudio Console is as below

[error as seen in RStudio Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l103R.png)

I went back to predict function in predictor1.R to line # 23, but its empty! I removed all the $ operators in that function, and the error still persists.

I have three files **server.R**, **ui.r** and **predictor1.R**

code for each is below:

**ui.r**

```
        library(shiny)
        shinyUI(
    navbarPage("PredictionApp",
               tabPanel("Predict",
                        fluidPage(
                            sidebarLayout(
                                sidebarPanel(
                                    textInput("phraseBox", "Enter a phrase:"),
                                    numericInput("noOfWords", "Enter no. of words to be predicted:", value = 1, min = 1, max = 1),
                                    actionButton("predictButton", "Predict"),
                                    br(),
                                    br(),
                                    # h5(strong("How to use the App")),
                                    # h5("Enter the phrase in first text box for which next word(s) have to be preidcted. In second text box, enter the number of word suggestions to be predicted for entered phrase."),
                                    # h5("The app fetches the last few words of the phrase and runs it through the ngram to generate the most predictable next word.")
                                ),
                                mainPanel(
                                    h3("Prediction App"),
                                    br(),
                                    br(),
                                    h4("Entered phrase:"),
                                    verbatimTextOutput("Text1"),
                                    h4("Next Word(s):"),
                                    verbatimTextOutput("Text2")
                                )
                            )
                        )
               )
        )
   )
```

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(tm)
library(RWeka)
library(stringr)

shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {
        #setwd("/Users/sahil/Documents/Data Science Course/Capstone")
        bigrams <- readRDS("bi_words.rds")
        trigrams <- readRDS("tri_words.rds")
        
        T1 <- eventReactive(input$predictButton, {
            input$phraseBox
        })
        
        T2 <- eventReactive(input$predictButton, {
            phrase <- input$phraseBox
            source("predictor1.R")
            nextWord <- predict(phrase,input$noOfWords)
        })
        
        output$Text1 <- renderText({
            T1()
        })
        
        output$Text2 <- renderPrint({
            cat(T2(), sep = "\n")
        })
        
    }
)
```

**predictor1.r**

```
library(stringr)

bigrams <- readRDS("bi_words.rds")
trigrams <- readRDS("tri_words.rds")

selectwords <- function(phrase) {
  phrase <- unlist(strsplit(phrase, "\\s+"))
  
  if (length(phrase) >= 2) {
    phrase <- phrase[(length(phrase) - 1) : length(phrase)]
  }
  else {
    phrase <- phrase
  }
}

predict <- function(phrase, noOfWords =1) {
  phrase <- selectwords(phrase)
  suggestion <- head(bigrams[grep(paste("^\\<", phrase[1], "\\>", sep = ""), bigrams["feature"]), noOfWords],)
  suggestion <- suggestion["feature[1]"]
  suggestion <- gsub(phrase, "", suggestion)
  
  suggestion <- unlist(strsplit(suggestion, "\\s+"))
  return(suggestion)
}
```

**head(bigrams) output**

```
> head(bigrams)
  feature frequency rank docfreq group
1     . .     14013    1    5831   all
2     ! !      6254    2    3070   all
3     : )      2110    3    2046   all
4  in the      1663    4    1618   all
5     . i      1652    5    1579   all
6 for the      1605    6    1586   all
```

**head(trigrams) output**

```
> head(trigrams)
         feature frequency rank docfreq group
1          . . .      7180    1    4806   all
2          ! ! !      2755    2    1543   all
3 thanks for the       489    3     487   all
4          ! : )       413    4     410   all
5          ? ? ?       346    5     232   all
6          . . i       333    6     324   all
```

PLEASE HELP  - ANY HELP ON THIS WILL BE GREATLY APPRECIATED. I hope i have provided enough clarity and context. if not, please let me know I can give all details required. THANK YOU in advance for your support!!!!

Comment: Difficult to help if we can't reproduce. Please include a few bigrams and trigrams in the code so it works without RDS files

Comment: HI Hubert, I have posted the output of the head(bigrams) and head(trigrams) function. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Your code works fine at my end without any error.

Comment: Hi Ronak,  - that's the most frustrating part. It was working fine on my end before also, but then started throwing this error. Thanks for checking